# How do I merge a list but separate with a new line?

Tags: python

### I have 3 lines of text (this is non-python config):

```
[[inputs.snmp.field]]
 name = "esxi-cpuload1"
 oid = ".1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2.1"
```

that I need copied 96 times with a number increment after "cpuload" and my oid, so for example esxi-cpuload2, cpuload3, etc, and .2, .3, .4 etc for my oid.

So far I've been able to do this with two lists using:

```
inputs = "[[inputs.snmp.field]]"
name = "esxi-cpuload"
oid = ".1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2."

name2 = [name+str(i) for i in range(97)]
oid2 = [oid+str(i) for i in range(97)]
```

which gives me two lists with the numbers (the first line of text doesn't need changing). However how would I now combine all this data using Python? Or is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you have some text you'd like to replicate with variable parameters. If so, that's a good use case for [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

```
FMT = '''
[[inputs.snmp.field]]
name = "esxi-cpuload{i}"
oid = ".1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2.{i}"
'''

text = ''.join(FMT.format(i = i) for i in range(1, 96))
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted with a simple solution, thanks a lot mate!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do we need the `''.join` portion?

Comment: @OtterVonBismarck It depends on your needs: you can join the pieces together into a single blob of text (as the example answer does) or you could create a `list` of separate pieces: `[FMT.format(i = i) for i in range(1, 96)]`.

Answer (score 0):

`'\n'. join(zip([inputs] * 97, name2, oid2))`

The first expression with inputs is converting that string to a single element array and then multiplying it by 97 makes that string repeat in the array 97 times.

Comment: I'm getting the following error:
    '\n'.join(zip([inputs] * 97, name2, oid2))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found

Comment: To get that to work you need a flatten `'\n'. join(a for b in zip([inputs] * 97, name2, oid2) for a in b)`.